# Xquery how to search for Boolean

Tags: json, xml, xquery, oxygenxml

I wrote XQuery to search in a JSON document. The code is the following:

```
xquery version "3.1"
let $characters := fn:json-doc("pott.json")?characters?*
return
    document {
        <characters>
            {
                for $s in fn:distinct-values($characters?name)
                return
                    if ( $characters[?name eq $s]?house eq "Hufflepuff")
                    then
                        (
                        <characters>
                        <name>"{$s}"</name>
                        <datas>
                        <name>"{$characters[?name eq $s]?name}"</name>
                        <id>"{$characters[?name eq $s]?_id}"</id>
                        <deatheater>"{$characters[?name eq $s]?deathEater}"</deatheater>
                        <school>"{$characters[?name eq $s]?school}"</school>
                        </datas>
                        </characters>
                        )
                    else
                        ()
            }
            </characters>
    }
```

But I also want to add a search for Boolean type, e.g: if the characters value for `deathEater` = `false`, then only show the characters which are belongs to the house `Hufflepuff` and `deathEater` = `false`. Here is my JSON file:

```
    {
      "characters":[
         {
      "house":"Slytherin",
      "orderOfThePhoenix":false,
      "name":"Phineas Nigellus Black",
      "bloodStatus":"pure-blood",
      "deathEater":false,
      "dumbledoresArmy":false,
      "school":"Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry",
      "role":"(Formerly) Headmaster of Hogwarts",
      "__v":0,
      "ministryOfMagic":false,
      "_id":"5a0fa6bbae5bc100213c2334",
      "species":"human"
     },
     {
      "house":"Slytherin",
      "orderOfThePhoenix":false,
      "name":"Regulus Black",
      "bloodStatus":"pure-blood",
      "deathEater":true,
      "dumbledoresArmy":false,
      "school":"Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry",
      "__v":0,
      "ministryOfMagic":false,
      "_id":"5a0fa772ae5bc100213c2337",
      "species":"human"
     },
     {
      "house":"Gryffindor",
      "orderOfThePhoenix":true,
      "name":"Sirius Black",
      "bloodStatus":"pure-blood",
      "alias":"Padfoot",
      "deathEater":false,
      "dumbledoresArmy":false,
      "school":"Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry",
      "animagus":"black dog",
      "__v":0,
      "ministryOfMagic":false,
      "_id":"5a0fa7dcae5bc100213c2338",
      "species":"human"
     },
{
      "house":"Hufflepuff",
      "orderOfThePhoenix":true,
      "name":"Amelia Bones",
      "bloodStatus":"unknown",
      "deathEater":false,
      "dumbledoresArmy":false,
      "school":"Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry",
      "role":"Head, Department of Magical Law Enforcement",
      "__v":0,
      "ministryOfMagic":true,
      "_id":"5a0fa842ae5bc100213c2339",
      "species":"human"
     },
     {
      "house":"Hufflepuff",
      "orderOfThePhoenix":false,
      "name":"Susan Bones",
      "bloodStatus":"half-blood",
      "deathEater":false,
      "dumbledoresArmy":true,
      "school":"Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry",
      "role":"student",
      "__v":0,
      "ministryOfMagic":false,
      "_id":"5a0fa86dae5bc100213c233a",
      "species":"human"
     }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Can you please help me how to do this, I've tried several functions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In XQuery, Booleans are written with the functions `true()` and `false()`. You can extend your condition as follows:

```
if ($characters[?name eq $s][?house eq "Hufflepuff"]?deathEater eq true()) ...
```

If you want to check if a value is `true`, you can omit `eq true()`:

```
if ($characters?deathEather) ...
```

Comment: Do I have to declare a namespace for true(), because i didn't have any result after running the code.

Comment: @ZoltanBilcsik, show us enough data to allow us to reproduce the problem, your sole sample data has `"deathEater":false` so obviously a check for `true()` can only fail and not return any data.

Comment: Okay, I'have added 2 more "character"

Comment: @ZoltanBilcsik, then also add your current query and the exact result you get and the one you want.

Comment: now i'm getting all the characters which are belongs to Hufflepuff with their name, id etc.. but I only want to get the characters where the value for "DeathEater" = false

Comment: @ZoltanBilcsik, no idea, it seems your current sample data doesn't have a single object with the value `Hufflepuff` at all.

Comment: I've added to more characters which are belongs to _Hufflepuff_

Comment: If you replace `?deathEater eq true()` with `?deathEater eq false()`, you should get the two results you’d probably expect.